# Ruby's def and instance_eval vs. class_eval

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm reading the Metaprogramming section of *Programming Ruby 1.9* and I'm having trouble understanding what's going on *internally* between `class_eval`/`class_exec` vs. `instance_eval`/`instance_exec`.

So first of all, my understanding is that `def` adds a method to the method table of `self` (the class object):

```
class A
  puts self  # => A
  def foo; 42; end  # added to the method table of self, so becomes an instance method
end
A.new.foo  # => 42
```

And if we use `class_eval`, we get the same behavior:

```
A.class_eval do
  puts self  # => A
  def bar; 42; end  # same as above
end
A.new.bar  # => 42
```

But somehow in the `instance_eval` case, things are different:

```
A.instance_eval do
  puts self  # => A
  def baz; 42; end  # added to the method table of an anonymous
                    # singleton class of self, so becomes a class method
end
puts A.baz  # => 42

s = 'string'
s.instance_eval do ... end  # same behavior, so now def creates an instance method
```

So I understand the functional difference between `class_eval` and `instance_eval`.

But the contexts inside the `class_eval` and `instance_eval` blocks look *exactly* the same to me -- in particular, `self` points to the same object, and the `local_variables` are the same.  So what's going on inside the blocks (internally) that's making `def` act different?

Is there some piece of documentation I could read?  The RDoc for [instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000334) and [class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001650) doesn't help.  Looking at the source, [instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.src/M000334.html) seems to set up a singleton class object whereas [class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.src/M001650.html) doesn't -- but is this difference visible outside the C code, on the Ruby level?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the fact that def does not depend on the current self, you might think about it as being a "current class" that has it's own rules.

Following your examples:

```
class A
  # defs here go to A
  puts self  # => A
  class << self
     #defs here go to A's eigenclass
  end
end

A.class_eval do
  #defs here go to A
end

A.instance_eval do
  #defs here go to A's eigenclass     
end

s = "Hello World"

class << s
  #defs here go to s's eigenclass
end
```

Here's the portion of the chapter that talks about the issue and it's pretty clear about the behaviour

> class_eval and instance_eval both set
>   self for the duration of the block.
>   However, they differ in the way they
>   set up the environment for method
>   definition. class_eval sets things up
>   as if you were in the body of a class
>   definition, so method definitions will
>   define instance methods In contrast,
>   calling instance_eval on a class acts
>   as if you were working inside the
>   singleton class of self. Therefore,
>   any methods you define will become
>   class methods.

The only thing I think is worth adding is that you can call instance_eval in any object, not just classes, and the behaviour doesn't change but has different consequences.

Some relevant reading:

[Ruby: instance_eval and class_eval method definitions](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/ruby-instanceeval-and-classeval-method.html)

[Chapter 4 of this most excelent series](http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming)

Comment: Hm, I see -- that makes sense.  Is there any way to inspect that "current class" in Ruby code?

Comment: I think in `A.instance_eval`, you meant to write `#defs here go to A's eigenclass`?  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: It's not exactly simple, I will post some relevant links in the answer

Comment: @krusty.ar: Google for singleton class, meta class, or eigenclass. (I have seen it referred to as all 3) It is an instance specific class that sits between the instance and the instances class in the inheritance heirarchy

Comment: @Matt Briggs: yes, I know, did I miss something in my answer?

Comment: Awesome -- I think I understand Ruby a little better now! :)  Thanks krusty, and Joerg too!

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @krusty.ar's answer: `def` and `define_method` add methods to the current *method definition context* (I believe that's what it's called, I'm not sure), not to the current `self`.

It's just that inside of a module, class or singleton class body, those two happen to be the same.

But, for example, in a script body (aka top-level), `self` is the `main` object, but the current method definition context is `Object`.

Comment: Thx for your answer. More detail would be helpful.